# Show a pointer in imageview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

[image]

I want to show image like this "with a pointed arrow in the left" in my Android app. I believe we will have to manipulate the bitmap somehow to do that.

Can anyone help on how to update the imageview to look like the above image with arrow in the left?

Thanks

Comment: this ? did u forget to put link ?

Comment: updated my question to say that what I am looking is the arrowhead or pointer image..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired effect using shaders, relevant tutorials:

http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/
http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/shaders/